# Make the default autocomplete of TexStudio to be current text

Tags: texmaker, texstudio

I've been trying out TexStudio (previously I used TexMaker). There are a lot of additional features I really like, but a serious handicap for my typing style is that TexStudio autocompletes to whatever the top choice of autocomplete is.

To be clear, I don't want to turn off autocomplete entirely. I just want to be able to type something like: `\fi` which has a top suggestion of `\figurename`, and hit `enter` and have it stay `\fi`. Whereas, if I want to actually use autocomplete, for example typing `\docu` to get `\documentclass` as a suggestion, I would like to have to hit an arrow key (say, the down arrow) to select it from the autocomplete list, *then* hit enter in order to trigger autocomplete.

Thus, in short if I type `\docu` and hit enter, I'd like it to be left as `\docu`. If I want autocomplete to change `\docu` to `\documentclass`, I'd rather have it require that I hit an arrow key or manually select it from the tooltip in order trigger the autocomplete.

Is it possible to get TexStudio to behave this way? As far I as I can tell, this is how it works in TexMaker.

Comment: Sounds like you'll be better off having autocomplete off? Then manually triggering autocomplete with Ctrl+Space when you need it. This saves you having to click Enter when you want `\docu` instead of `\document`.

Comment: You can play with `Completion` options. I do think you are looking for unchecking `Complete selected text when non-word character is pressed` (available only in advanced options).

Comment: I do have the "complete selected text when non-word character is pressed" unchecked as I do want to be able to open braces without having autocomplete guess what I really meant, but it doesn't solve the above problem unfortunately.

So far, it looks like I might have to turn autocomplete off, and then manually trigger it, but often I use autocomplete more because it happens to pop up on a tooltip and I notice, rather than deliberately triggering it, so if I require manual usage I'll probably just never use it. Hence why I asked if some middle ground is possible.

Comment: I don't understand: what use is the autocompleter if you want exactly what you typed instead of the completed word? Like, how often is it that you require cmds like `\docu` instead of `\document`? That you are willing to go through the extra trouble of clicking "down arrow + enter" on the other times you actually want autocomplete?

Comment: I do think that's what you are looking for. But if you hit "Enter" you will get the autocompletion suggestion. You could rather type `space` or, as required, `{`.

Comment: I write a *lot* of custom TeX code and I'm too lazy to keep making the custom autofill files that TexStudio requires. So the vast majority of commands I actually use on any given document tend to not be default commands. Nonetheless autocomplete will try to replace the command with *something* because it assumes I am trying to write a default command.
I'd say any given command is maybe 50/50 that it will show up at all on the autocomplete list, and I don't want to fix autocomplete's assumptions that regularly.

Comment: I do to, but your custom command will either be followed by a space or by an open brace, so my suggestion applies, doesn't it?

Comment: @gusbrs There are times when you don't want space or braces after a command because it inserts whitespaces, which can error in a tex primitive situation, which I use often. And since not many people do actually use tex primitives, they hardly ever show up on TexStudio autocomplete list. Nonetheless your suggestion is the best I've been able to find so far, I was just hoping there was a better solution than that.

Comment: A "\" also works. I guess I'm not grasping your settings properly. Well, that was my best bet...

Comment: You are declaring these commands with `\newcommand` etc.? I have two more suggestions: one is to add these custom commands into a cwl -- this way `\docu` actually shows up as the first item on the autocompleter list. Second is to use `Esc` instead of `Enter`, if `{` or `space` is not what you actually need at that point in time.

Comment: Thanks Troy and gusbrs;
I do know how I can work around the current problem, it was more a question of setting the default behavior though, not how to adapt to the current behavior.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure it's not a setting currently available in the options (that is, the behaviour you desire). But for all the custom commands you have, write a .cwl file. It's the canonical solution, *not* a workaround imo. Since, you only need this behaviour insofar as it concerns your custom commands right?

Comment: If that's any relief, I must say I'm also annoyed by this behavior. I feel the autocomplete is too "pushy", and there's plenty of times I wish the selection would just be chosen if somehow "navigated" with arrows/tab or whatever.

Comment: Well, I will regularly write new custom commands on the fly as I realize I am using the same general block of information repeatedly in a document. So that would basically involve writing a new .cwl file every time I write a new .tex document, which is... unrealistic. It's worth writing a .cwl file for the core commands I use regularly (if I can use autocomplete), but it still won't resolve the problem fully.